# Initializing the same mutex again

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

What happnes when i initliaze the same mutex variable again?
According to pthread_mutex_init() man page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init

It should fail with errno set to EBUSY

Why don't i see this behavior? below code executes just fine.

```
lock = (pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
if (pthread_mutex_init((pthread_mutex_t*)lock, NULL) != 0)
{
    printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
    return 1;
}

if (pthread_mutex_init((pthread_mutex_t*)lock, NULL) != 0)
{
    printf("\n mutex init failed %d\n", errno);
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: I am just trying to stimulate a situation where i got EBUSY in an integrated system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that it says that "The pthread_mutex_init() function **may** fail if ...". That means the implementation is not required to perform these checks, and apparently yours doesn't.

Take a look at the [corresponding POSIX page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html)'s list of errors:

> The pthread_mutex_init() function *will* fail if:
>
> [EAGAIN]
>       The system lacked the necessary resources (other than memory) to initialise another mutex.
>
> [ENOMEM]
>       Insufficient memory exists to initialise the mutex.
>
> [EPERM]
>       The caller does not have the privilege to perform the operation.
>
> The pthread_mutex_init() function *may* fail if:
>
> [EBUSY]
>       The implementation has detected an attempt to re-initialise the object referenced by mutex, a previously initialised, but not yet destroyed, mutex.
>
> [EINVAL]
>       The value specified by attr is invalid.

You'll notice that `[EBUSY]` is in the "may fail" section. So it is not a guarantee but only something an implementation is permitted to do.

This kind of thing is often a bit surprising to people who aren't used to reading standards or formal API documentation. The choice of wording is deliberate, and the word "may" generally indicates something that is permitted to happen. The word "will" (or, less commonly, "shall") is used to express a guarantee.

Also, `pthread_mutex_init` actually returns the error code, if there is one, it doesn't set `errno`. From the man page you cited:

> If successful, the pthread_mutex_destroy() and pthread_mutex_init() functions shall return zero; otherwise, an error number *shall be returned* to indicate the error.